# Как рисовать окружную рамку treeview при обработке customdrawitem в delphi

Tags: delphi

Привет всем! 
Посмотрите мой код который окрашивается TTreeViewEx наследника от TTreeView:

```
 
  function TTreeViewEx.CustomDrawItem(Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState;
  Stage: TCustomDrawStage; var PaintImages: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  NodeRect: TRect;
  procedure DrawSelection;
  begin
    if FSelectionBold then
      Canvas.Font.Style := Canvas.Font.Style + [fsBold];
    if FFocused then
      Canvas.Brush.Color := GetShadowColor(clHighlight, 60)
    else
      Canvas.Brush.Color := GetShadowColor($F0F0F0, -10);
  end;
begin
  Result := True;
  inherited CustomDrawItem(Node, State, Stage, PaintImages);
  if Result then
  begin
    if (Stage in [cdPrePaint]) then
    begin
      Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
      if FSelectionBold then
        Canvas.Font.Style := Canvas.Font.Style - [fsBold];
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
      if cdsHot in State then
      begin
        if Node  Selected then
          Canvas.Brush.Color := ApproximateColor(clBtnHighlight,
            clHighlight, 256 / 9)
        else
          DrawSelection;
      end
      else if cdsSelected in State then
        DrawSelection;
      NodeRect := Node.DisplayRect(not RowSelect);
      if RowSelect then
      begin
        NodeRect.Right := BoundsRect.Right;
        NodeRect.Left := BoundsRect.Left;
      end;
      Canvas.FillRect(NodeRect);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Теперь как можно рисовать рамку вокруг выбранного как в рисунке [image: Windows проводник]

Answer (score 1):

Все началось от поставление плюс и минус в Button:

```
 
  procedure TTreeViewEx.CreateWnd;
  begin
    inherited CreateWnd;
    SetWindowTheme(Handle, nil, nil);
  end;
```

И сделать RowSelect

Answer (score 0):

А зачем тебе все своими силами рисовать? Обычно Custom Draw используется, чтобы изменить какие-то детали (шрифт например, или добавить иконку, или типа того).
Вообще, если хочешь все сам рисовать, тогда смысле в Custom Draw особого нету - проще Owner Draw делать. Это общие соображения, если без привязки к Delphi, возможно там есть какие-то особенности.

Ну в любом случае, винда это рисует через Theme API. DrawThemeBackground и подобное. Вот похожий вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930695/how-to-draw-ttreeviews-styled-selection-rectangle-during-advancedcustomdrawitem

Answer (score -1):

Все решил.

```
if (cdsSelected in State) and Focused then
  DrawFocusRect(Canvas.Handle, NodeRect);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы отформатировать код, используйте отступ в четыре пробела (выделить код и нажать Ctrl+K).